# Display Files and Folders on Gridview

Tags: c#, image, gridview, uwp, directory

I have files and folders on "koleksibuku" folder. I want all the files and folders in the "koleksibuku" folder is displayed on the gridview. If the folder using images on: "ms-appx:///images/folders_png8761.png", whereas if the files using image bindings. How do I display all the files and folders on a gridview?

Note: In the "koleksibuku" folder is not necessarily files and folders. Folders created by the user with the folder name in accordance with the wishes of the user.

Note:
"koleksibuku" folder on local package

Answer (score 0):

I won't go into details, just a hint:

```
var gridViewItems = gridView.Items;

var folder = await ApplicationData.LocalFolder.GetFolderAsync("kolesibuku");
foreach (var item in await folder.GetItemsAsync()) {
    if (item.IsOfType(StorageItemType.Folder))
        processFolder(gridViewItems, (StorageFolder) item); // Add folder element to gridView
    else if (item.IsOfType(StorageItemType.File))
        processFile(gridViewItems, (StorageFile) item); // Add file element to gridView
}
```

Comment: I get an error message like in the picture: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4oRSWSS0hKDZDdGVlhaZEVFV0U/view?usp=sharing. And I have one more question, how to display if the folder using images on: "ms-appx:///images/folders_png8761.png", whereas if the files using image bindings?

Comment: @Rose there is a small mistake in @cyanide's answer. It should be `foreach (var item in await folder.GetItemsAsync())` not `foreach (var item = await folder.GetItemsAsync())`.